# How to make a record belong to all options of a field

Tags: sql, drupal, database-design, drupal-views

I have a database of records called "services", each service has about 30 attributes and each service has an associated country as an attribute. The problem is some services are offered to ALL countries. On the front end of this database I have a drop-down menu that selects all the records based on a country filter. How would I be able to include the service offered to ALL countries without needing to duplicate the record for the service and replacing the country name.

P.S. For those interested in the actual implementation, I am using Drupal nodes to represent each service and a view with exposed filters to select the country. But if I have to do some SQL work then I can do that too.

Comment: here is the dev site, http://dev.capri-finance.aegir.exterbox.com/ the records with ALL have not yet been included

Answer (score 3):

Your `WHERE` clause would follow this pattern

```
WHERE (CounrtyID = PassedVariable OR PassedVariable = 'all')
```

Comment: This worked!!, There is also a Drupal views filter option to Allow for and "OR" alternative

Comment: Unfortunately, WHERE (Passedvariable="All") is not valid, apparently I had written where countryid="All" which gave a different result